# Binding matrix arrays to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have 3 string arrays like this:

```
public string[] RowHeaders
{
    get { return new[] {"RowHeader1", "RowHeader2", "RowHeader3", "RowHeader4"}; 
}

public string[] ColumnHeaders
{
    get { return new[] {"ColumnHeader1", "ColumnHeader2", "ColumnHeader3"}; }
}

public string[][] Values
{
    get { return new[]
    {
        new []{"Value11", "Value12", "Value13"},
        new []{"Value21", "Value22", "Value23"},
        new []{"Value31", "Value32", "Value33"},
        new []{"Value41", "Value42", "Value43"},
    }; }
}
```

Array sizes are unknown until run-time (array values in code snippet are for showing the concept). I want to create a WPF grid from them like

[image: Grid with array data]

which binds to these 3 arrays and designed entirely in XAML (if possible). How?

Comment: create newGridControl that inherit from `Grid` and put there 3 `DependencyProperties` ColumnHearder, RowHeader, ItemsSource and generate it automatically using code

Comment: @safi, nice idea. Thank you. I am working on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here a solution using DataTable and MultipleBinding,
in the xaml pass the three arrays to an IMultivaluesConverter:

```
<Grid>
   <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders"/>
                <Binding Path="RowHeaders"/>
                <Binding Path="Values"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

then in the converter manage those arrays to create a DataView that will be bond to the Grid ItemSource :

```
 public class MatrixToDataViewConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{            
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var myDataTable = new DataTable();
        var colums = values[0] as string[];
        var rows = values[1] as string[];
        var vals = values[2] as string[][];
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("---");    //The blanc corner column
        foreach (var value in colums)
        {
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(value);
        }
        int index = 0;

        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            var tmp = new string[1 + vals[index].Count()];                
            vals[index].CopyTo(tmp, 1);
            tmp[0] = row;
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(tmp);
            index++;
        }     
        return myDataTable.DefaultView;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

output :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. Do you have any idea how to make row headers styling like column headers and remove last blank row?

Comment: To remove the last blanc row just set the CanUserAddRows :  <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False"> ..and about the Style of the first row Column, i am not sure but try setting the DataGridRowHeader Style

Comment: How can I also update the cell background color using the same method?

Comment: Quick Question: will the view of the values change if the values 2d array gets changed by some method called during runtime? Thanks!