# WPF How to use GridView to display a matrix

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I am new to WPF programming and I am trying to convert my python program into a UWP app just for practice. The app can dynamically creates new text entries and labels to allow users to input the entries of matrices.

[image: Python Version]

I am currently stuck in how to create a grid to put those text entries and labels. I thought a right choice would be using gridView but the examples that I have seen don't seem to help. Any ideas on how to implement that?

This is my current try:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" Margin="0,150,0,0">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I am also trying to access the Columns attribute of the gridView (System.Windows.Controls) but it seems I am using the wrong gridView (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls). But VS can't find the correct gridView for me as it doesn't exist. I am very confused with GridView. Can anyone provide some pointers?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question for stackoverflow, you may first learn on how to us GridView (https://wpf-tutorial.com or https://www.wpftutorial.net), then when you meet a concrete problem you may come and ask here (after looking if question already exists).

Comment: @Siegfried.V Thank you for your suggestion but I have looked for examples and I am not sure whether GridView would give me the result that I expect.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I think your question is : `WPF - How to bind a GridView to a Matrix` or `How to display a Matrix in WPF`, if I understood good what you want, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018974/binding-matrix-arrays-to-wpf-datagrid) seems a good solution to your problem on how to bind your Matrix to DataGrid.

For that you need to :

- create two ObservableCollection< int >(or ObservableCollection< string > lists in your `ViewModel` 
  (For example ListRows and ListColumns)
- When you edit your textboxes, you will update ListRows or ListColumns by updating the corresponding ObservableCollection

So using binding, the GridView will automaically update.

But before starting with it, I you need some notions with `Binding`, `ViewModel`, `ObservableCollection` and `Converters`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my VS doesn't seem to have DataGrid. Or perhaps the app that I am developing doesn't support DataGrid?

Comment: After some attempts I have found out that the package that contains DataGrid is not compatible with my app. Any substitutes?

Comment: do you have using System.Windows.Controls in your .xaml.cs file?

Comment: No. VS can't find it. And installing that package failed as it seems incompatible with my app.

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean by "incompatible"? Do you have a minimum notion on how assemblies are added? Try that : select your project, then Add->Reference, in the menu select Assembly->PresentationFramework, without that assembly VS will not recognize System.Windows.Controls.

Comment: I am sorry for potential inappropriate phrasing as I am using the Chinese version of VS. And incompatible was what VS reported in Chinese when I was trying to install the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit. I thought this package contained the DataGrid. I am also not sure if I followed your instruction correctly due to the language issue. I clicked Project->Add Reference->Assembly->Framework but it was empty. And the Extension below the Framework contains a lot of stuff but System.Windows.Controls is still not there.