# WPF ListView - column header not as property, but as Key of Dictionary (Dictionary is ListViewItem property) - ComparisionMatrixControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I would like to make a MatrixControl in my WPF app. First thing it starts from ListView and defines 'MatrixLine' in the model. ListView ItemsSource was an ObservableCollection. I have a simple complete model that shows what I'm aiming for and a picture with the result I expect for the created model.

I have a problem with how to add the 'MatrixLine' property type of Dictionary, [Keys] as a columns header in the ListView and [Values] (boolean) as a sign 'x' on te ListView. (The picture with the result that follows)

**Expected result for my model**
[Result for my model creating in ViewModel constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvwaI.png)

**GitHub Project**
https://github.com/Varran/WPF_Multiporownywarki_Baza

**Model**

```
public class ColorBase 
    {
        public string Name { get; }   
        public int Saturation { get; private set; }  
        public ColorBase(string name, int saturation)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Saturation = saturation;
        }

        public void ChangeSaturation(int newSaturation)
        {
            Saturation = newSaturation;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"ColorBase: {Saturation.ToString().PadLeft(4, ' ')} - '{Name}'";
        }
    }

    public class MixedPaint
    {
        public string PaintName { get; } 
        public List<ColorBase> Ingredients { get; }

        public MixedPaint(string name)
        {
            Ingredients = new List<ColorBase>();
            this.PaintName= name;
        }

        public MixedPaint AddIngredient(ColorBase color)
        {
            bool added = false;

            foreach (var item in Ingredients)
            {
                if (item.Name == color.Name )
                {
                    item.ChangeSaturation(item.Saturation + color.Saturation);
                    added = true;
                }
            }

            if (!added)
                Ingredients.Add(color);

            return this;
        }        
    }

    public class MatrixLine
    {
        public ColorBase ColorIngredient { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool> Matrix;

        public MatrixLine(ColorBase color)
        {
            Matrix = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            this.ColorIngredient = color;
        }

        public void AddToMatrix(MixedPaint mixedPaint)
        {
            string paintName = mixedPaint.PaintName;
            bool doesItContainIgredient = mixedPaint.Ingredients.Any(o => (o.Name == ColorIngredient.Name &&
                                                                        o.Saturation == ColorIngredient.Saturation));
            Matrix.Add(paintName, doesItContainIgredient);
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MixedPaint> mixedPaints;
        public ObservableCollection<MixedPaint> MixedPaints { get { return mixedPaints; } }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private MixedPaint selectedMixedPaint;
        public MixedPaint SelectedMixedPaint {
            get { return selectedMixedPaint; }
            set { selectedMixedPaint = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedMixedPaint)); } }

        private ObservableCollection<MatrixLine> comparisonMatrix;
        public ObservableCollection<MatrixLine> ComparisonMatrix  { get { return comparisonMatrix; } }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            ColorBase yellowA = new ColorBase("YellowA", 110);
            ColorBase yellowB = new ColorBase("YellowB", 175);
            ColorBase blueA = new ColorBase("BlueA", 77);
            ColorBase blueB = new ColorBase("BlueB", 135);
            ColorBase redA = new ColorBase("RedA", 95);
            ColorBase redB = new ColorBase("RedB", 225);
            ColorBase whiteA = new ColorBase("WhiteA", 200);

            MixedPaint greenA = new MixedPaint("GreenLight")
                .AddIngredient(yellowA)
                .AddIngredient(blueA);
            MixedPaint greenB = new MixedPaint("GreenDark")
                .AddIngredient(yellowB)
                .AddIngredient(blueB);
            MixedPaint orangeA = new MixedPaint("OrangeLight")
                .AddIngredient(yellowA)
                .AddIngredient(redB)
                .AddIngredient(whiteA);
            MixedPaint orangeB = new MixedPaint("OrangeDark")
                .AddIngredient(yellowB)
                .AddIngredient(redB);
            MixedPaint violet = new MixedPaint("Violet")
                .AddIngredient(redA)
                .AddIngredient(blueB);

            mixedPaints = new ObservableCollection<MixedPaint>() { greenA, greenB, orangeA, orangeB, violet };
            SelectedMixedPaint = greenA;

            List<ColorBase> uniqueColorsBase = new List<ColorBase>();

            foreach (var item in mixedPaints)
                foreach (var item2 in item.Ingredients)
                    if (!uniqueColorsBase.Contains(item2))
                        uniqueColorsBase.Add(item2);

            uniqueColorsBase = uniqueColorsBase.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ThenBy(o => o.Saturation).ToList();

            comparisonMatrix = new ObservableCollection<MatrixLine>();

            foreach (var color in uniqueColorsBase)
            {
                MatrixLine line = new MatrixLine(color);
                foreach (var mixed in mixedPaints)
                    line.AddToMatrix(mixed);

                comparisonMatrix.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_multi_próby.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_multi_próby"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="ListOfMixedPaint" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="List of MixedPaint:"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MixedPaints}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMixedPaint}" Margin="10">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="PaintName: "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PaintName}" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="IngradientCount: " Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ingredients.Count}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="BOM"
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Ingredients of selected MixedPaint"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedMixedPaint.Ingredients}" Margin="10">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Color Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Color Saturation" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Saturation}" Width="100"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="MultiComparerOfPaints"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Multicomparer of paints"/>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ComparisonMatrix}" Margin="10" FontFamily="Cascadia Code" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Unique ingredient" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ColorIngredient}" Width="180"/>
                        <!-- no idea how binding -->
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is my solution.
I do not fully understand this solution yet, but I will have to try.

[**DataMatrix in WPF - codeproject**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37241/Displaying-a-Data-Matrix-in-WPF)

or

[**Binding matrix arrays to WPF DataGrid**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018974/binding-matrix-arrays-to-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).